# Using boolean expression in order by clause

Tags: sql, mysql, postgresql

I have an order by clause that looks like:

```
( user_id <> ? ), rating DESC, title
```

Where ? is replaced with the current user's id.

On postgresql this gives me the ordering I'm looking for i.e. by current user, then highest rating, then title (alphabetically).

However on MySQL I get an unclear order current user is neither first nor last, nor is it by rating or title.

Is my only option for cross database compatibility to replace this quick and dirty boolean expression with a CASE WHEN .. THEN .. ELSE .. END statement?

Edit: Thanks all for the assistance, it is as correctly pointed out by Chaos and Chad Birch the case that the problem lies elsewhere *(specifically that I'm using the results of the above query as input into the next - then acting surprised that the order of the first is lost ;)*

Comment: This should work fine, I would look for another problem that might be causing it. Add "(user_id <> ?)" to the SELECT clause if you want to confirm that it's giving the right values (should be 0 for current user, 1 otherwise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested several variations on this in mysql and they all worked correctly (the way you're expecting).  I suppose your problem has to be somewhere other than the query.  To verify for yourself, I suggest running an equivalent query directly from mysql client.

Answer (score 12):

MySQL has no *real* notion of booleans, and simply maps `TRUE` and `FALSE` to the numeric values `1` and `0` repectively.

In this case `user_id <> ?` will return 0 for the majority of the rows in your table and 1 for the other rows. The default sort order is `ASC`, meaning in all likelihood the rows you want are at the **bottom** of your result set (`0/FALSE` come *before* `1/TRUE`). Try modifying your query to accommodate this.

```
( user_id <> ? ) DESC, rating DESC, title
```

Assuming this is indeed the issue, cross-database compatibility can be achieved with ease.

```
IF(user = ?, 0, 1), rating DESC, title
```

Comment: I should point out that I am not familiar with PostgreSQL's particular flavour of SQL. I have assumed the existence of a simple IF() function as is the case with MySQL, but if it does not exist I apologize and will leave the appropriate corrections as an exercise for the reader :)

Comment: It doesn't exist, but simply using `(boolean expression) DESC` as in your first example works.

Answer (score 3):

You could try doing a

```
select (user_id <> ?), user_id
```

to see that you are getting the right true/false values showing up.