# Order by value, but disregard zero

Tags: mysql

Can you help me out here?

I'm doing a simple SQL-query for a calendar, which lists a number of values (date, time etc as UNIX-time), according to their values and limited to 5 entries.

The relevant part of the querystring is this:

```
ORDER BY specialtime DESC, `start` ASC, programstart ASC
```

The column named "specialtime" lists these values:

```
432000
259200
172800
0
0
0
0
```

That's almost ok - but I would like entries with a value, different from zero to appear in ascending order - and after them, the rest, also ascending... like this:

```
172800
259200
432000
0
0
0
0
```

Is there a way to make this happen in SQL without relying on post-processing the values?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check if special time is 0 and sort by that expression primarily:

```
ORDER BY specialtime = 0, specialtime ASC, `start` ASC, programstart ASC
```

MySQL [treats boolean expressions as integers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/591608/using-boolean-expression-in-order-by-clause), so false evaluates to 0 and true evaluates to 1. You can sort by such an expression and every row where specialtime = 0 evaluates to true is moved to the bottom of the list.

Or, slightly longer, but also more portable and perhaps easier to understand:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN specialtime = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, specialtime ASC, `start` ASC, programstart ASC
```

The CASE expression returns 0 (of specialtime is not 0) or 1 (if specialtime is 0). The query is sorted primarily on this value, so all the `0` times are at the bottom of the list. So basically the functionality is the same, but the version with `case` is more portable, since not many databases allow sorting by a boolean expression.

The value of specialtime is used for secondary sort, so withing that group when `specialtime = 0` returns false, the records are still sorted on the actual value of specialtime.

Comment: Real nice. Strictly MySQL-specific, but, then, the question is about MySQL

Comment: @PM77-1 That's what I thought, although I've now added a more portable version too.

Comment: You may want to mention that MySQL has integer representation of true/false, to explain how your 1st solution works.

Comment: Fortunately I found a question about that subject, so that saves a bit of explaining. ;-)

Comment: Works flawlessly, both of them :) Thank you